# Complex integration and Residue theorem. Where did I mistake the calculation?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I have to calculate $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+a^2} (a>0)$ using complex integral.

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{z^2+a^2}$.

Integral Contour ($r<R$);

$C_1 : [r,R], z=t,t:r\to R$

$C_2$ : Circle that has radius $R, z=Re^{i\theta}, \theta : 0\to 2\pi$

$C_3$ : $[R,r], z=te^{2\pi i}, t: R\to r$

$C_4$ : Circle that has raius $r, z= re^{i\theta}, \theta : 2\pi \to 0$

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\int_{C_2} f(z) dz, \displaystyle\int_{C_4} f(z) dz \to 0\,\,({r\to 0, R\to \infty} )
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
&\displaystyle\int_{C_1} f(z) dz \to \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+a^2} dx.\\
&\displaystyle\int_{C_3} f(z) dz \to -e^{i\pi}\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+a^2} dx
=\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+a^2} dx.
\end{align}

From Residue Theorem,
\begin{align}
2\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+a^2} dx
=2\pi i[\text{Res}(f, ai)+\text{Res}(f, -ai)]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\text{Res}(f, ai)
=\dfrac{(ai)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2a i}
=\dfrac{e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}}{2\sqrt{a}i}\\
&\text{Res}(f, -ai)
=\dfrac{(-ai)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{-2a i}
=-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}}{2\sqrt{a}i}\\
\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+a^2} dx
=\pi i \left[\dfrac{e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}}{2\sqrt{a}i}-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}}{2\sqrt{a}i}\right]
=\dfrac{\pi }{\sqrt{2a}}i.
\end{align}
So $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+a^2} dx=0.$

But answer is
$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+a^2} dx=\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2a}}$. Maybe, my calculation is wrong, but I cannot find where I mistook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have cut along the positive real axis, the second residue is $-e^{3 \pi i /4}/(2 \sqrt ai)$ leading to,
\begin{align}
2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + a^2} dx 
&= \frac{2\pi i}{2\sqrt a i}
\Big( e^{\pi i/4} - e^{3 \pi i / 4} \Big) \\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}} \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt 2}
\end{align}